# Arduino disecting a string

Tags: arduino-uno

Hello I have a String that contains the following: "println('hello world')".
I want to be able to remove everything from the String except for the text insie the brackets. Bear in mind that this text will change multiple times as the programme runs. How can I remove everything except for what is in the brackets from the string.

```
    String line1 = "println('hello world')";
```

Please help me thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I remove everything except for what is in the brackets from the string?

There are a number of [String class](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) member functions that can help with this. First, [indexOf(val)](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringIndexOf) will help locate the character of interest. Second, [substring()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringSubstring) will help cut out the part you want. And as a bonus, using [lastIndexOf()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringLastIndexOf) will allow brackets within the string.

```
String s = "println('hello world')";
s = s.substring(s.indexOf('(') + 1);
s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(')'));
```

Cheers!